# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) - Splitting time column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

[image: Chip time]

This is the chip time column in the dataframe

I have used the below code to convert everything in minutes, but I am getting an error:

```
time_list = df7[' Chip Time'].to_list()

time_mins = []
for i in time_list:
# used strip to remove trailing space
    i = i.strip(' ')
    m, s = i.split(':')
    math = (int(m)*60 + int(s))/60
    time_mins.append(math)
df7['Runner_mins'] = time_mins
df7.head()
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-7afde4a258f4> in <module>
      6 for i in time_list:
      7     i = i.strip(' ')
----> 8     m, s = i.split(':')
      9     math = (int(m)*60 + int(s))/60
     10     time_mins.append(math)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Expected output]

Can someone tell me what is the mistake made?

Comment: Likely i is more than 2 entries when you split it on line 8, so it can't be unpacked into just "m, s". Try assigning i.split(':') to a another variable and printing that.

Comment: @samm82 the value of i is 36:21, I want to split it and store in m=36, s=21 and compute the operation, the output should be 36.350000 as shown in expected output.

Comment: @samm82 when I tried to split and print m, s using the same line of code m,s=i.split(':'), it getting printed correctly. But when I run the whole program, I am getting an error.

Comment: Can I ask why you don't just use pandas.to_datetime(). then use the .dt. accessor on the series to access the minutes and seconds as attributes of the series?